# Angular js - Redirect to a page ,from inside controller using $http

Tags: angularjs

Below is my function inside controller.

### controller.js

```
function saveAndMove()
        {           
            User.save({
                userId: $scope.user.id
            }, $scope.user, function(result) {
                console.log(result);                
            });  
            $http.get('/logout').success(function(data) { 
             console.log("Sucess redirect");
            }).error(function(data){
                console.log("Failure redirect");
            });

         }
```

Here I am getting "Success redirect" message in my console. But I am not redirected. Please let me know where I went wrong.

Comment: What does your server code look like for the `/logout` route?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to make a route change within a controller, you need to use a url alteration service.  Angular has $location built in for just this purpose.  I don't endorse your `save` method or the usage of `logout` response... but use `$location` ([docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location)) to perform the actual redirection after the promise resolves.

```
 function saveAndMove($location)
    {           
        User.save({
            userId: $scope.user.id
        }, $scope.user, function(result) {
            console.log(result);                
        });  
        $http.get('/logout').success(function(data) { 
             $location = 'route/to/wherever';
        }).error(function(data){
            $location = 'route/to/handlerforfailuretologout';
        });

     }
```

Comment: Yet redirect is not happening. My code is $location='/'. Also, while handling '/logout' also I have a res.redirect('/'). But still its not happening. But I have a GET / 302 831ms in my command prompt

Comment: have your written any tests to ensure your code is executing the way you intend?  `$location` is **very** straightforward.  If you're not redirecting, then your `$http` call isn't processing the way you intend.

Comment: Hi, I found one thing now. Since, I had a 'GET /signup' message in the console, I tried opening a new window in browser and typed localhost:3000 . this time it directed me to the signup page by default.  If in case, i removed the call to 'logout' then by default when i type localhost:3000, it moved to localhost:3000/user/home. So I guess there is some refresh page problem (I dont know the technical term in angular js). Will u please help me here.

Comment: there is a WHOLE bunch of related code in everything you're talking about, and there is really no way that I can assist you with a "fix it like this" type of answer.  It sounds to me like your entire approach is off base, and that's far beyond the scope of this one question.  You want to redirect inside a controller? Use `$location`.  For help beyond that, I suggest checking out codereview stackexchange. there's just no way to help you with something like that here. sorry! :(

Comment: Short remark as of AngularJS 1.3 it should be $location.path('/route/to/wherever') instead of $location 'route/to/wherever).